# How to shrink an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Having this snippet

```
int main() {

  char *obstacles[3*3]

  char map[3][3] = {'D','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' '};

  int k = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (map[i][j] == '*')
        obstacles[k++] = &map[i][j];
    }
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Leads to me to this situation:

[image: pic]

How do I shrink this array to a `k`-cells array?

Comment: You can't. Also, I want to note that this isn't static allocation, it's automatic allocation.

Comment: It would help to explain the reason why you need to shrink the array in the first place, this smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is declared with a fixed size, there's nothing you can do about it. Its size is chosen at compile time and you have no way of modifying that when the program runs. What you can do however is to use [`malloc()` and `realloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), if you really wish to do so. I don't really see a good reason to do that though: it's only 9 pointers, you're not going to have any advantage in reducing that.

You can initialize the array as `char *obstacles[3*3] = {NULL}` (all cells set to `NULL`) and then later stop at the first `NULL` cell when scanning it. This is a common way to avoid passing around the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of the array.  The best you can do is keep track of the number of elements it contains in a separate variable.